# how to use auto to declare a couple of variables deeply?

Tags: c++, c++17, auto

If I have a map, I can use auto to declare variables like

```
map<int, float> m;
for (auto[i, f] : m) {
    ...
}
```

If the map is

```
map<int, pair<float, bool>> m;
for (auto[i, [f, b]] : m) { // not right
    ...
}
```

How can I still use the `auto` to declare a number of variables together?